# Pullback of Riemannian volume form under diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ and $N$ be two oriented Riemann manifold. Let $\varphi:M\to N$ be the orientation preserving diffeomorphism. Prove the Riemann vol form after pull back is given as follows:

$$\varphi^*dV_g = dV_{\varphi^* g}$$

Where $g$ is the Riemann metric on $N$.

My attempt: First note that if pick a local orthonormal frame on $N$ as $(E_1,...,E_n)$ then $dV_g(E_1,..,E_n)  = 1$,Now we change the frame into $(d\varphi^{-1}(E_1),...,d\varphi^{-1}(E_n))$ then it's again a local frame  on $M$ but not necessarily orthogonal in metric on $M$ but it's orthogonal in metric $\varphi^* g$ hence we have $dV_{\varphi^*g}(d\varphi^{-1}(E_1),...,d\varphi^{-1}(E_n)) = 1$ while $\varphi^*dV_g(d\varphi^{-1}(E_1),...,d\varphi^{-1}(E_n)) = dV_g(E_1,..,E_n)  = 1$,since all the oriented orthnormal frame on $(M,\varphi^* g)$ has the form $(d\varphi^{-1}(E_1),...,d\varphi^{-1}(E_n))$ .

Hence we have the desired conclusion, Is my proof correct? It's there some better proof?

Comment: $M$ needs not be equipped with any Riemannian metric besides $\varphi^*g$ for what you are trying to show. If $(N,g)$ is an orientable Riemannian manifold and if $\varphi\colon M \to N$ is a diffeomorphism, then $(M,\varphi^*g)$ is an oriented Riemannian manifold with Riemannian volume form $\varphi^* \mathrm{dVol}_g$ by what you have written.

Comment: thank you ,in fact this is an exercise in Lee's IRM exercise 2.42